# Error: Signature verification failed when trying to mint tokens

Tags: spl-token, mint

I get the error when trying to mint tokens on web3 with `mintToChecked` function.

Here's the code:

```
async function mintToken(
    connection: web3.Connection,
    payer: web3.Keypair,
    userAddress: web3.PublicKey
) {
    const tokenMint = await spl.createMint(
        connection,
        payer,
        userAddress,
        userAddress,
        8
    );
    console.log("token mint: ", tokenMint.toBase58());

    const userTokenAddress = await spl.createAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        payer,
        tokenMint,
        userAddress
    );
    console.log("user token address: ", userTokenAddress.toBase58());

    const tx = await spl.mintToChecked(
        connection,
        payer,
        tokenMint,
        userTokenAddress,
        userAddress,
        100,
        8
    );
    console.log("mint tx: ", tx);

    const userTokenAmount = await connection.getTokenAccountBalance(
        userTokenAddress
    );
    console.log("user token amount: ", userTokenAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mint transaction isn't being signed by `userAddress`, since you're passing in a `Pubkey` instead of a `Signer`. Assuming you have `userSigner`, where `userAddress = userSigner.publicKey`, you should do:

```
    const tx = await spl.mintToChecked(
        connection,
        payer,
        tokenMint,
        userTokenAddress,
        userSigner,
        100,
        8
    );
```

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. 
Don't understand why it also accepts PublicKey, if it needs a signer.

Comment: In the case of a multisig, you pass in the Pubkey of the multisig, then the actual multisig participants sign in the `multiSigners` parameter, so it doesn't *always* need a signer. Agreed that it's unclear, especially since multisigs aren't very common